# Lucene - exclude fields from being searched

Tags: lucene, kentico

I have a search index and require a lucene query which will conditionally search specified fields. The end result will be that if you're logged into the website, all fields will be searched, or if you're logged out, specified fields will be skipped by modifying the lucene query.

The closest I have at the moment is:

```
+(term1~ term2~) +_culture:([en-gb TO en-gb] [invariantifieldivaluei TO invariantifieldivaluei]) **-FieldToIgnore1:(term1 term2) -FieldToIgnore2:(term1 term2)**
```

The problem with this however is if one of the search terms exists in one of the fields not mentioned (FieldToIgnore1 or FieldToIgnore2), then the document is ignored because it's been excluded as one one of the fields to ignore were matched.

How can this be modified so lucene doesn't even match against the fields to ignore?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Generally, it's pretty easy to ignore a field.  You just *don't search* on that field.  Are you using a `MultiFieldQueryParser` or something?  Or is your default search field a catch-all field of some kind?  Or what?

Comment: Apologies - I'm not too familiar with Lucene terminology, but I believe it's the catch-all field option. The functionality is being built with [Kentico CMS's smart search](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Smart+search+syntax), which uses [Lucene query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html) if that helps?

Comment: In that case, there likely isn't a way to tell which field the match is coming from.  That "all" field is going to be just a big bag of words.  You will likely need to write your query to search *only* the fields you want (or perhaps index a separate search field that combines only the fields you want to search on). I don't know anything about Kentico, though, so I don't know if it has any support for tuning your index and such.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of qualifying your search via Lucene and the Smart Search Results webpart, have you tried modifying the searchability of the document fields themselves. You can set search parameters on the Page Type or index itself.

Go to Page Types --> [your doc type] --> Search fields, and set what fields are and aren't exposed to searching.

[image: Page Types --> Articles --> Search fields (v.8.2)]

Version 9 gives you these settings in the Smart Search app. See [these docs](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Defining+general+indexes) for details.

Comment: Thanks Emma, I've considered this, but then disabling the searchability for the fields to ignore won't suit the conditional aspect of the requirement where if you're logged in, then it would search everything. I think perhaps my only option is to create a custom search index which excludes these fields - I was just hoping there'd be a simpler option which could be handled by lucene...

Comment: If Lucene is still janky (I've had mixed luck with entering conditions like you) and the search scope varies based on general users and authenticated users, then what you could do is put in two search (or search results) webparts. Set the visibility on one to `Display to roles: _notauthenticated_` and the other to `Display to roles: _authenticated_`

Comment: Then the webpart for logged on users could hit all the fields in the search index (skip Lucene); the other would be blocked for those fields with Lucene `-term`